# how to call ajax loader

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

i have build a small function whose work is to change banner image path when the user clicks on "a" tag. it works fine but when i click on "a" tag it changes image. but it is taking a bit of time because size of the image is heavy. so i want to put ajax loader till the time the image loads itself.

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.control').find('a').click(function(){

        var path= $(this).text();

        $('#banner').find('img').attr('src','images/' + path +'.jpg' )

        })


    })


</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="banner">
<img width="500" height="300" src="images/first.jpg" />

</div>
<div class="control">
<a href="#" id="first">first</a>
<a href="#" id="second">second</a>
<a href="#" id="third">third</a>
<a href="#" id="forrth" >fourth</a>


</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this one

[jQuery Loadmask](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-loadmask/)